# Add Group in one domain to another group in another domain

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add groups from one domain to another but having a tough time doing it..some points:

- I am a domain admin in both domains.
- There is a trust setup between the two domains
- If I manually add via GUI ADUC then I am able to add said group from one domain to another group in another domain - no problem doing it that way.

Scenario: Domain1 has a group that exists on there. Domain2 has multiple groups and I need the group from Domain1 to exists on all groups in Domain2.

Here is what I have tried (and failed):

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity GROUP_DOMAIN2 -Members "CN=GROUP_DOMAIN1,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=local" -Server DC_FROM_DOMAIN2
```

> Error: Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=GROUP_DOMAIN1,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=local' under: 'DC_FROM_DOMAIN2'

Trying the other way round I get the same issue:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity GROUP_DOMAIN2 -Members "CN=GROUP_DOMAIN1,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=local" -Server DC_FROM_DOMAIN1
```

> Error: Add-ADGroupMember : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation

Another attempt:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity GROUP_DOMAIN2 -Server DC_DOMAIN1 -Members "CN=GROUP_DOMAIN1,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=local" -Verbose
```

> Error: Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'RES-UV-NCES-SQL82-Admins' under: 'DC=lseg,DC=stockex,DC=local'.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated...

Comment: Have you checked the group scopes? I believe there are three: Domain Local, Global, and Universal. Not all of those group types can be accessed/shared across multiple domains. If the group you're trying to add to another domain is a domain local group I don't know if that would work. I'm no expert, but I hope this helps somehow (: